# When commiting with `--squash` option, how should I go about the commit message?

Tags: git

I recently started using `git commit --fixup` and `--squash` options. I use `--fixup` option for, ehm, fixups. When I commit with `--fixup` option, commit message is constructed automatically. For example, when I commit

```
$ git commit -m '[#123] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

then I do some minor editing

```
$ git add .
$ git commit --fixup :/123
```

will autogenerate commit message `fixup! [#123] Lorem isum dolor sit amet`. However, when I use `--squash` option instead, such as

```
$ git add .
$ git commit --squash :/123
```

git will run text editor and ask me to write the commit message, but at the same time, it will generate and insert in the editor the default commit message `squash! [#123] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`.

My question is: What is the best practice for writing `--squash` commit messages? With `--fixup` option, there is no confusion, because git will autogenerate the message and give me no choice of editing it. But with `--squash` option, git on autogenerates the message on one hand, but gives me the option of editing it on the other hand. The conundrum is, if I always just accept the autogenerated message `squash! [#123] ...`, what is the purpose of git giving me the opportunity to edit it, and what is the purpose of having `--squash` option in addition to `--fixup` if it does the same thing? I am afraid that if I edit the message in a wrong way, git will no longer recognize the commit as intended to be autosquashed to the original `[#123]` commit.

Comment: it basically comes down to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758662/2266261 In short, fixup commit message is ignored and the original message is kept, with squash you have the possibility to change the message.

Comment: @Dunno, I am asking _how_ to write a good `--squash` message.

Comment: My take is that it boils down to the same distinction between the "squash" and "fixup" actions in the rebase script you edit after running `git rebase -i` and before that script is executed to actually run the rebasing process. Basically "fixup" is a *stronger* form of "squash" because it does the same thing "squash" does but throws away the commit message. So here's the distinction: squash means "I want the change of this commit be integrated into that commit". Since there are now *two* changes in the same commit, and you're supposed to *document* the changes a commit implements, you're given

Comment: ...a chance to edit the message of the resulting prospective commit. "fixup", on the other hand, is for "oopsie!" cases when you just, say, forgot to add a new file or did a stupid typo or something like this. IOW, the commit being squashed adds no *logically distinct* change and hence there's no need to document it. As you can see, your question sort of not makes real sense: in the message of a commit to squash into another, you document the change about to be squashed into.

Comment: Well, to maybe restate all that in different words: if you don't know what to write in the commit message of the commit to squash into another, use fixup.  Otherwise explain there what this commit implements, and why -- as you do with every other commit.

Comment: @kostix, what you say are generalities. What I need is concrete guide. Canned experience.

Comment: Ah, that's simple: always write "I have no idea" as the squash commit message. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kostix, I'm getting a hang of it, lol