# Git - Remove commit from history but lesve the code

Tags: github, commit

I am using git on VS2019

I was wondering if there is a way to remove old commits but always keep the latest code. The reason is that when I work on a big change, I do a lot of commits after checking every small step but at the end it is annoying when I click on view history and need to search an old commit to compare the changes. I would like to remove specific commits but leave the changes.  In that way I will see on history only the main milestones of the developing process. There is a way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like in these scenarios, you're developing a new feature, in which case you should be using a branch+pull request approach to development. During the pull request, you can do a squash merge. It's not all in the command line, but that might be for the best anyway.

If you're already working within a feature branch, then I like [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463987/6557000)'s approach.

Comment: how can I do it in visual studio?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with VS. The best I can do is point you to the documentation from Microsoft: 

[branch creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branches?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)
and
[pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pullrequest?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the git rebase feature.

If you know how many commits you want to squash together, you can use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

You can also do it in interactive mode:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~N
```

Be aware that if you merging commits you have already pushed, you may have trouble with your next push.

For more details, see: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a workflow similar to "[Git better with fixups](https://dev.to/atulify/git-better-with-fixups-5bo7) " from [**Atul Sharma**](https://dev.to/atulify)

For the commits which are incremental improvement for the *same* step, use `git commit --fixup small step`, which allows you to "do a lot of commits after checking every small step".

(You can see it in [Git Extension in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16758131/6309))

But at the end, you can cleanup all those small steps with `git rebase --interactive --autosquash <First step commit>` (assuming you have not pushed those commits yet)

That way, you end up with a cleaner history.