# How do I use Git's interactive rebase with a local-only repository (no remote / origin)?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, git-rebase, remote-branch

I use git as a local source control system mostly for history and diff tracking.  I still want to use rebase to do fixup / squash on WIP commits that I will make periodically.  When I try to do `git rebase -i` though, I get the following:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> MyBranch
```

It seems like git doesn't expect you to use interactive rebase without an upstream remote?  How do I do that?

Comment: simply use `$ git rebase -i HEAD~4`  ref [What does it mean to squash commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703556/what-does-it-mean-to-squash-commits-in-git/50443893#50443893). Here "HEAD~4" means to specify the commits as using the last four commits from where the HEAD is.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`git rebase -i` in shorthand, without specifying a destination branch, will make git assume that you are trying to rebase against a remote branch tracked by your branch. That's why the error message is mentioning stuff about remotes.

When you do specify a target, git will rebase against that [commit-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git):

```
git rebase -i <commit-ish>
```

Comment: You can track any branch, local or remote.

Comment: Yeah - tried to edit the answer to point that out, because I basically re-edited my original self answer to be the same.  `HEAD~3` here is not an essential part of the syntax, it's just one (of any) possible `commit` refs.

Comment: `HEAD~3` is only there because your original answer attemps to rebase on `HEAD~3`, and going through unnecessary steps to acheive it. I can put commit-ish if you prefer...

Comment: This answer should explain what "commit-ish" means or at least link to it like mcw0933's comment on the other answer

Answer (score 25):

So in short - if you have 3 local commits and you now want to interactively rebase/squash/etc them:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

(See Sébastien's explanation !)

Comment: Yup - thanks @MikeW.  That is one concrete example of what you can use for the "commit-ish" parameter to git.  

For anyone unfamiliar with what a "commit-ish" is... check out this other SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git