# Git rebase: no tracking information

Tags: git

I am using `git version 2.9.0.windows.1` and I want to rebase a local repository (no remote). 
But I always get

> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
>   Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
>   See git-rebase(1) for details.
>
> git rebase
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>
> git branch --set-upstream-to=/ master

I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3` as suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625213/how-do-i-use-gits-interactive-rebase-with-a-local-only-repository-no-remote), but it doesn't work in my case.

If I simply copy the repository to my Linux machine, git rebase works fine.
I checked with `git config --list` on both machines, they seem almost the same.

So I am wondering what makes git rebase doesn't work on my Windows machine.

**UPDATE**
I did a test for a small case, see my history:
[git history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EJky.png)
and rebase:
[git rebase message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA4za.png)

No matter what option I use with `git rebase`, I got the same message

Comment: "it doesn't work": what error message do you see?

Comment: @VonC message `There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to rebase against. See git-rebase(1) for details...`, like I posted. There is no editor popup which allows me to change the commit history.

Comment: It sure looks like you've hit a bug in this particular leading-edge (bleeding-edge) version of Git.

Comment: @torek Actually no: that but was seen as soon as git-for-windows 2.7.0 (January 2016)

Comment: I see: not a bug in Git per se, and not all that new, some sort of weird interaction causing problems with a (the?) Windows port of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase -i HEAD~3` should work unless:

- you are in a branch which has not 3 commits (but only 2 or one since the first commit),
- you are not in a branch (detached HEAD: check with `git branch -vv`)
- you are affected by [issue 704](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/704) and [issue 710](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/710)

> I added `bash.exe` to [MacType](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype) utility exclusion list, now all is good.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't think that is the reason. I updated the question with pictures of git history and rebase message: the branch has 3 commits and HEAD is at the tip of the branch

Comment: @NAX Do you have the same error with `git rebase -i @~3 @` or `git rebase -i @~3 branch`? (`@` is a shortcut for `HEAD`)

Comment: @NAX Do you have the same error in a regular CMD session (not git-bash)?

Comment: @NAX in a CMD as well?

Comment: @NAX I have seen bugs affecting git bash, and edited the answer to reference them.

Comment: Try to unzip the portable git distribution (no setup) in a simple path without spaces, and try to set your PATH, still in a CMS session, to a minimum. Then try again.

Comment: @ VonC amazingly... I don't know what happened, but you are right... if I quit MacType, git rebase just works fine. Anyway I think if I put bash.exe to the exclusion list, should also good. Thanks!

Comment: Note to self: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/32194151-git-rebase-fails-for-branches-that-lack-the-tracking-information-even-when-the-upstream-branch-is-explicitly-provided