# git rebase origin/develop fails with information about tracking information

Tags: git

`git rebase origin/develop` fails with information

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
```

This doesn't make sense to me as I explicitly specify the branch.
I'm pretty sure I have used this command before many times like this and it worked. This is true that this branch doesn't have tracking information but it doesn't have to and I don't want it to.

Here is listing of my `git branch -a`:

```
  develop
  master
* resolve
  test
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Any ideas?

Git version: 2.9.0.windows.1
OS: Windows 7

Comment: What about `git rebase origin/develop resolve`?

Comment: @1615903 I receive the same error message as before

Comment: Is it the same bug as http://stackoverflow.com/a/37875545/6309? (ie: what git version are you using, and on which OS?)

Comment: It seems like this is the same or very similar problem. I have updated my question with git version and OS.

Comment: Does the same solution apply? "if I quit MacType, git rebase just works fine. Anyway I think if I put bash.exe to the exclusion list, should also good"

Comment: I'm not sure what is MacType and what exclusion list they are talking about.

Comment: @Vistritium http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-windows-fonts-look-like-mac-fonts/ (exclude: https://github.com/mono0x/dotfiles/blob/master/mactype.ini#L41)

Comment: @Vistritium Exclude MActype: http://superuser.com/a/646893/141

Answer (score 0):

Please try a

git pull remotebranch

git branch --set-upstream-to=remotebranch

Sometimes when we drop and re-create a remote, the tracking information stored by the original fetch might get lost. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do I need to setup tracking information? I explicitly tell git what branch I want to rebase against. This branch is not supposed to have any tracking information - it's for local purposes only.

Comment: Sorry. Works well in my system. With GIT version 2.5.3.windows.1 and Windows 7. Must be a bug? Discussion in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964697/2949612 answer you need to set **origin/develop** branch as **upstream** branch for **reslove** branch.

Step **1:**

```
git branch --set-upstream resolve origin/develop
```

Step **2:**

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

I hope its helps you.

Comment: But I explicitly tell git what branch and what remote I want to use, setting upstream branch should not be needed in this case (as said in the answer you linked too). I would need to setup up-stream if I would want to execute "git rebase develop" but this is not my case.