# How to squash non-sequential commits

Tags: git, tortoisegit, squash

I have a feature branch that I've been doing work on and committing at save points along the way. During this process, I had to merge the develop branch into my feature branch to pick up some bug fixes that another developer did. So my commit history looks something like this:

- In progress #4
- In progress #3
- Merge develop into feature branch
- In progress #2
- In progress #1
- etc...

I want to squash all of the "In progress" commits but leave the merge commit in place. How can I do that using either command line or TortoiseGit?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why

Comment: when I do rebase i use interactive mode, i.e. `git rebase -i HEAD~6` so in first prompt I will take out the `Merge develop into feature branch`  thats how I will do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I squash two non-consecutive commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921708/how-do-i-squash-two-non-consecutive-commits)

Comment: I think I got the question answered 5 years ago. ;) Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentiones in the comment, you can do a `git rebase` with preserve merges option. And then reorder the commits and squash them