# how do I squash two commits from a non-master branch into one in git?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

Actually, I used the command git log: it showed commits made by me + commits others made to the master branch.
I have to squash two commits made by me for a pull request into one.
and I made commits using a non-master forked branch.
Please guide me.

Comment: I don't think you are phrasing your question correctly.  Two commits on the same branch do not need to be merged, they are already merged.  If you mean merging 2 commits on two different branches that's different.

Comment: You can't stash 2 commits on a single branch. You can ofc stash commits and merge them to a different branch, if thats what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about squashing multiple commits together? This is a good guide: https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt-android/wiki/Squash-All-Commits-Related-to-a-Single-Issue-into-a-Single-Commit

Comment: @EMcG , you are write probably i did phrase question properly , actually i want to squash two of my commits into one. please guide.

Comment: @TheInfectedDrake Please see the edited question.

Comment: @AdilB , Yes i read that but when i try to squash, it also squash the other commits done recently by others. see https://github.com/coala/coala/pull/5847/commits

Comment: @ASHOKSINGH see this answer for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921708/how-do-i-squash-two-non-consecutive-commits

Comment: @AdilB Thank you very much , I am looking forward it.

Answer (score 1):

To squash commits locally you can do it in this way.

Find hash of commit before commits that you want to squash. Use `git log` for it.

Next, you can use rebase:

```
git rebase -i hashOfYourCommit
```

After that, you'll see an editor with a list of all commits after this that you specify.

You can easily specify what do you want to squash (Change `p` to `s` near commits that you want to squash).

The last step, change the message of your commit.

If you want to squash a few groups of commits after the first one you need to use `git rebase --continue`. But everything should be visible in the console.