# How to squash 2 pairs of non-consecutive commits?

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, git-commit

What I have is:
`A -> B -> C -> D`

My aim is to get 2 commits like `A+C` and `B+D`. What I am thinking is:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Making the commits

```
pick A
squash C
pick B
pick D
```

Now, I will move the head back

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

If I understand correctly this should move the head to B.
So I can do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2

pick B
s D
```

And finally I move back the head with:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

And I am done. Is this a possible/reasonable solution?

I have found ways to squash 2 commits here - [How do I squash two non-consecutive commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921708/how-do-i-squash-two-non-consecutive-commits).

Comment: reorder the lines? `pick A squash C pick B squash D`?

Comment: In fact https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921708/how-do-i-squash-two-non-consecutive-commits is the answer. It's just not _exact_

Comment: so does `pick A squash C pick B squash D` suffice in my case?

Comment: I would assume so. If you create a branch before rebasing (something like `git branch mybackup`) you can always reset back to that after rebasing if you don't like it `git reset --hard mybackup`