# Can I merge a branch into an old commit and preserve a tag?

Tags: git

My use case is this:

1. tagged master v1.0
2. did some changes in master
3. live bug means I need to patch v1.0
4. I create a branch from the v1.0 commit make the changes and commit
5. I then tag the branch v1.0.1

I then want to merge the branch back into master. If I do this the v1.0.1 tag ends up being after the changes in master at point 2 (as you would expect).

I am guessing the answer is no, but is there anyway to merge the branch into the commit so that my 1.0.1 tag is attached to the commit after v1.0 and before the other changes in master. In effect ripling my change forward in time I suppose.

Or is the problem really my workflow, and I should have made my changes in 2 in a branch and only merged them to master when they were live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag is immutable, so your issue is more about the order of commit.

What you can do is rebase `master` on top of branch v1.0.1:

```
git checkout master
git rebase v1.0.1
```

That way, the two new changes in `master` are replayed on top of `V1.0.1`.
If you hadn't published master yet, a rebase is a convenient way to integrate fixes into your current branch.

See "[`git rebase` vs `git merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge)" for more.

---

As [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637129/graham-christensen) points out in the comments, if your changes on `master` were already pushed, rebasing them can spell troubles for your colleagues having already pulled `master`.
See "[Rebasing and what does one mean by rebasing pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715085/rebasing-and-what-does-one-mean-by-rebasing-pushed-commits)".

In that case, it is bast to:

- make your changes on a '`next`' branch
- merge `V1.0.1` in `master` (which then reflects at all times what is running in production)
- merge `next` in `master` when ready

(but if `next` needs the patch, then yes, you will be forced to apply it *after* your changes, because said changes have been already published, i.e. pushed to a remote repo)

Comment: Awesome. Git gets better the more I find out about it.

Comment: The one thing you need to be careful about is changing history after you've already pushed code. If you have pushed, then changing history means you have to force your push - and then any developers have to force a pull. Forcing it can cause people to lose work, so just be careful. I would say yes, your workflow is broken and you need to branch more.

Comment: @Graham: correct, this is why I mentioned "If you hadn't published master yet" in my answer. For more, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715085/rebasing-and-what-does-one-mean-by-rebasing-pushed-commits

Comment: @Ian: I have updated my answer to take into account the publication case (even though it doesn't apply in your case)