# Go back before commit and push changes

Tags: git

In my local environment I made several changes, then:

```
$ git log --oneline
2aa8998 Changes 02
5131bfe Changes 01
$ git commit -am "Commit 03"
$ git push

$ git log --oneline
9ca6c56 Changes 03
2aa8998 Changes 02
5131bfe Changes 01
```

But I noticed what I made a mistake, as I return to commit 2aa8998 before "git commit -am "Commit 03" with the changes without commit?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but `git rebase -i HEAD~3` might work for you.

Comment: You can (see @pfnuesel), but you really shouldn't. Never rebase pushed commits. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715085/rebasing-and-what-does-one-mean-by-rebasing-pushed-commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` aside, `reset` is made for this.

```
$ git reset HEAD^
```

will move your current local head (`master`, maybe?) one step up in history, while keeping your local files untouched.

Then for the `push` (and you should listen to @jeremytwfortune in his comment), you can (but shouldn't) remove it from your remote, by forcing the `push`.

`git push` will not work, but `git push -f` will. `-f` stands for force, it will apply the push at the risk of losing data.