# when not to use "git rebase" while working with GIT branches?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I've been learning Git recently and came to know `rebasing` is good in some cases to avoid merge commits and keep history clean.

Also I read that extra care should be taken while using `git rebase`.

Can someone please describe some cases in answers below, 
**in which cases using `git rebase` is a bad choice.**

Comment: I know question is little broad but we can summarize cases here that can help beginners like me.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Answer (score 9):

**Case 1:** We should not do Rebase on branch that is public, i.e. if you are not alone working on that branch and branch exists locally as well as remotely rebasing is not a good choice on such branches and it can cause commits with same changes but different SHA ids.

**Case 2:** We should not do Rebase on pushed commits, i.e. If you are working on branch `br1` and you already have pushed some commits to this branch on remote (or origin) you should not do rebase on this branch `br1`. Check this Question for reference: [Rebasing and what does one mean by rebasing pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715085/rebasing-and-what-does-one-mean-by-rebasing-pushed-commits)

Comment: Case 1 is a valid point and agreeable but case 2 is at some scenarios to have a clean commit history you'd want to rewrite the history unless the branch is not diverged at any point.
So my point here is , one can still rebase the tip and use --force-with-lease option while pushing which cautiously rewrites the remote history

Comment: What is a bubble commit?

Comment: @rakeshmehra same changes with two different commit SHA ids. (sorry for confusion it is in house term we used during git training)